# dwr log error handler

Tags: java, dwr

when i log in into my webapp dwr start their execution, and after that make this error log:

```
18-11-2009 12:09:13 [http-8080-Processor24] ERROR org.directwebremoting.util.LogErrorHandler
- Line=7 Element type "filter" must be declared. 18-11-2009 12:09:13 [http-8080-Processor24] ERROR org.directwebremoting.util.LogErrorHandler
- Line=91 The content of element type "allow" must match "(create|convert)*".
```

What does it means? I've no idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me that you have a problem in dwr.xml config. The error is saying that the xml config is not validating the dwr schema.

Please check this page: http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/server/dwrxml/index.html

Or please post your dwr.xml config and it would help to find the problem.